# WPF Binding User Entertainment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have ran into a situation where I have an ItemsControl generate a pretty complex visual tree from a data collection, dead simple:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

The small problem I have is when the initial binding construction occurs it can take a "noticeable" amount of time when it is building itself (anywhere from 1/2 a second to 2 seconds depending on tree complexity). During this period the UI thread is completely unresponsive (animations hang, clicks are unregistered, etc).

Virtualization is already enabled and working, so essentially all I want is the ability to play an animation while the ItemContainerGenerator does it's thing.

Comment: Have you tried setting most of your bindings to `IsAsync=True`?

Comment: @HighCore Nope, but I sure as heck will try that now.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a LARGE number of items, don't you?

Comment: @HighCore IsAsync worked great, thanks a bunch, post it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting most bindings to [`IsAsync=True`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<SomeControl SomeProperty="{Binding SomeData, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the UI not freeze during this, you can put the load of the Items data into a BackgroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Then in the end of the BackgroundWorker's method, notify that the Items property have changed.

Comment: The data is already loaded and good to go, the hang is caused by the binding engine itself creating the visual objects.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then. But anyway, I think the UI will not freeze only if the heavy processing part is put on another thread, I would recommend trying a solution with threads if its possible.